# Messages get removed from inbox if replied to or forwarded

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I had made some changes in Gmail and now if I reply to or forward an email it deletes the original from my inbox automatically. If I want it back in inbox then I need to search the for the email using the subject and then add the inbox label which returns it to the inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you aren't clicking "send and archive" when sending a reply. The archive command strips the inbox label from the mail. If that message/conversation didn't already have a label then the only way to find it is by searching all mail.

To hide the "send and archive" button then go to:

Settings/general/ "Hide "Send & Archive" button in reply" section

Answer (score -1):

go to settings and check / delete your filters

[image]